# Entity Framework Core: Assign default value in DB modal for nullable columns in Database when retrieving Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an already existing DB table with nullable integer column called **TotalAmount**. While the DB model reflecting this table has the property **TotalAmount** as int [not nullable int=> int?].

Is there a way to assign a default value for this property if it's **null** when getting the data from this table?

I don't want to have **int?** field and I can't change the Column in the DB to make it not nullable.

Comment: Are you using code first? Is there any error when you retrive data that has null value?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a constructor in the entity class for example. So whenever you create the class, a default value will be inserted for this field.

Example:

```
public class SomeEntityClass {
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public int TotalAmount {get;set;}
  
  public SomeEntityClass(){
    TotalAmount = 100;
  }  

}
```